# HTML5 video stream arrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, websocket, stream, video-streaming, arraybuffer

Server sends video as arrayBuffers and streams them to client using websockets.
On the client side i receive arrayBuffers in real time. So, is there any way to launch video stream using these arrayBuffers via HTML5 video tag?

Example of arrayBuffer:

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource

Comment: It is not working with media source am receiving unfragmented mp4 in chrome:media-intervals.

Comment: did you figure this out yet?

Comment: @SahithVibudhi i'm sorry for late response, but no, i haven't figured out

Comment: I could not make it work with media-source. I ended up updating source object on every new buffer reception with new URL.createObjectURL()

Comment: Have you got the solution yet? I'm now facing this problem.